# Riot.js: Toggle class on label if input has value

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I need to toggle class `.has-data` on `label` if `input` has some data

```
<label>
    <input type="text">
</label>
```

Can it be done just using some markup without writing javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'll have to write some JavaScript, but the JavaScript is pretty minimal. Change the HTML to this:

```
<label class="{ has-data: entry }">
    <input type="text" onkeyup="{updateEntry}">
</label>
```

And add this section to the component's script:

```
<script>
  this.entry = '';

  updateEntry(e) {
    this.entry = e.target.value;
  }
</script>
```